# Using another answer's improvement in your own answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Hypothetical scenario:

Person A writes a review for a question. He writes a improvement X. Person B also writes a review for the question, after person A does. Person B has something to add to improvement X and uses (for example) the new function from the improvement that person A wrote.

My scenario:

[This question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95707/very-ugly-tkinter-calculator/) was [answered by Ethan Bierlein](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/95712/59481). I [wrote an answer for it too](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/95716/59481), but I used a function that Ethan wrote in his answer in my answer.

Is this sort of thing okay, or should I have left a comment to Ethan's answer as something he could add to his post?

Comment: I think this happens a lot. Just saying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is acceptable and happens quite regularly. To be honest, I'm always glad when it happens.

Take a look at the following answers for example. [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/95014/52915), @glampert (person A) posts an answer in which he mentions multiple good points. In one of the next answers, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/95093/52915), @Edward takes one of those points and elaborates it further. Both answers are very valuable.

Comment: I'm sure there have been meta questions about this topic before, I just can't find them.

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly ok to post answer that contains a point from another answer, with some improvements added,
*if you give credit to the user you're borrowing from*.

It can be as explicit as:

> ... as @abc mentioned in his answer...

Or as subtle as:

> ... in addition to using a `Map` instead of a `List` (thanks @abc!)...